# Keeping a UnityPlayer alive through fragments

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have an activity with a subview which loads the UnityPlayer into it.  This UnityPlayer works well and as expected.  Then I open a new fragment into this activity, this fragment also has a view which loads a UnityPlayer into it.  This UnityPlayer also works well and as expected.

The problem arises when I exit the fragment, returning to the activity.  Here the UnityPlayer is frozen and the program will eventually crash.  Does anyone have an idea (or pointers) on to how to use the UnityPlayer in different views like this?

For Example:

When the Activity opens I use this to initialise my view:

```
public void init(Context context) {
    inflate(context, R.layout.exercise_3d_animation_layout, this);

    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(context);

    FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.unity_player);
    frameLayout.addView(mUnityPlayer);
    mUnityPlayer.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

Then within my activity there are all the normal Unity-Android callbacks:

```
// Quit Unity
@Override protected void onDestroy ()
{
    mUnityPlayer.quit();
    super.onDestroy();
}

// Pause Unity
@Override protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mUnityPlayer.pause();
}

// Resume Unity
@Override protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mUnityPlayer.resume();
}

@Override protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    mUnityPlayer.start();
}

@Override protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    mUnityPlayer.stop();
}

// Low Memory Unity
@Override public void onLowMemory()
{
    super.onLowMemory();
    mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
}

// Trim Memory Unity
@Override public void onTrimMemory(int level)
{
    super.onTrimMemory(level);
    if (level == TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL)
    {
        mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
    }
}

// This ensures the layout will be correct.
@Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
}

// Notify Unity of the focus change.
@Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}

// For some reason the multiple keyevent type is not supported by the ndk.
// Force event injection by overriding dispatchKeyEvent().
@Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE)
        return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

// Pass any events not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
@Override public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)     { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)          { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
/*API12*/ public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)  { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
```

And when the fragment opens it will initialise the view again (same as before) . I think my problem is in understanding the lifecycle of both and how they interact

Comment: Interesting question, but it would help if you showed us code. In this case it would be fairly difficult to give us something reproducible (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but ya gotta at least give us something to look at!

Comment: Ah yes, sorry there is just so much that I wasn't sure what to add.  I will look through my code and edit the question once I figure out what to show :)

Comment: Most likely the activity, and anything in the fragment during the closing phase of the lifecycle (pause, destroy, detach, etc)

Comment: How about the error log? PS, those are the activity callbacks, but they're separate from the fragments callbacks

Comment: You probably want to move most of these events to your fragment instead of your activity. Also, you mention 2 unity fragments, but i only see 1 mUnityPlayer

Comment: The weird thing is there are no errors, the view in the activity with the UnityPlayer is frozen (and I can keep opening and closing the fragment which continues to work with it's own UnityPlayer).  Then when I exit the activity, the parent activity it goes to is frozen and will eventually just close.  Best finds in the logs include: W/Unity: Timeout while trying detaching primary window.

Comment: Still sounds like you're calling Fragment operations from an Activity

Comment: Okay, after thinking some more here are my new thoughts: so you cannot destroy mUnityPlayer or the activity closes completely (mUnityPlayer.quit() closes it), so what I want is to keep the same player alive, in this case I will only have the callbacks in the activity (as both views connect to the activity).  When the new fragment opens, I think I could pass the view containing mUnityPlayer to the fragment, and then not destroy the fragment when it closes. I am not sure if this will work, or is good practice though...

Comment: mUnityPlayer.quit() closes it's parent activity? That doesn't sound right, but been a long time since I've touched the android player

Comment: What I meant before is that it looks like you're calling your functions in the wrong place. Your unity view is in a fragment that you're destroying, but you're keeping the reference in your activity. onDestroy/onStop isn't called when your fragment is destroyed, its called when your activity dies (in this case). If you want the former, you need to move your callback functions from Activity to Fragment

Comment: mUnityPlayer.quit() kills the current process, which shuts down the activity from my understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this!

Basically in the base activity have the onStop() and onDestroy() methods only occur when the activity isFinishing() then use a singleton UnityPlayer (singleton only within the activity context though, destroy when changing activity).  This is needed as a lot of the main UnityPlayer methods are static and you cannot call or create two separate Unity Players.

When opening the new fragment, detach the first UnityPlayer from it's layout (so it doesn't have a parent when connecting it to the next view).  Do this when exiting the fragment too.  Make sure to handle onPause() and onResume() correctly too to avoid black screens. This also fixes orientation change issues if changing layout :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems unityPlayer.quit() does in fact kill it's process when called.

> You can stop this behavior by specifying a different process name
>   (f.i. ":unity") for the UnityPlayerActivity in the Android Manifest.
>   It seems UnityPlayer kills its process when quit() is called so you
>   just have to be sure your Application and other Activities have a
>   different process name (by default it's the Application package name).

https://answers.unity.com/questions/587979/how-do-i-stop-munityplayerquit-closing-the-entire.html

Comment: This stops the entire app being shut, it doesn't help when just closing a fragment unfortunately, I need to be able to keep the activity alive when the fragment containing the view is destroyed, but thanks for your help anyway! I'll keep trying :)

Comment: Really hard to understand what you're doing and aiming for without more source code, sorry! Your question says you have 2 unity players, but sounds like you only want one..